# Menu driven program ends in an infinite loop

Tags: c, linux, do-while

I have been struggling to figure out a way to enhance the error checking in my simple menu driven C code shown below. The code works fine with the right inputs, but unfortunately it goes in an infinite loop when an incorrect argument is given. Can somebody please help me handle this case?

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int choice, num, i;
    unsigned long int fact;
    system("clear");
    do
    {
        printf("1.Factorial\n");
        printf("2.Prime\n");
        printf("3.Odd/Even\n");
        printf("4.Exit\n");
        printf("\nYour choice?");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        switch(choice)
        {
        case 1:
            printf("\nEnter number:");
            scanf("%d",&num);
            fact = 1;
            for(i=l;i<=num;i++)
                fact=fact*i;
            printf("\n Factorial value=%lu\n",fact);
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("\n Enter number:");
            scanf("%d",&num);
            for(i=2;i<num;i++)
            {
                if(num%i== 0)
                {
                    printf("\n Not a prime number.\n");
                    break; 
                }
            }
            if(i==num)
                printf("\n Prime number.\n");
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("\nEnter number:");
            scanf("%d",&num);
            if(num %2==0)
                printf("\n Even number.\n");
            else
                printf("\nOdd number.\n");
            break;
        case 4:
            break;
        default:
            printf("\nInvalid Argument.\n");
        }
    }while(choice != 4);
    return 0;
}
```

The code works fine with the inputs `1,2,3,4 and any other integer` but when I enter a character or string, the code goes in an infinite loop. Why? How to handle this case?

Comment: Indentation, please. This code is really hard to follow slammed hard left like that.

Comment: check for the return value of `scanf()`. The `scanf()` function will return zero when a character or string is entered.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -g`). Then **use the debugger** `gdb` (which you should learn to use).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check for the return value of the `scanf()` function. Something like this:

```
if((scanf("%d", &choice)) != 1){
    printf("Invalid Argument\n");
    continue;
}
else
{
    //Your switch case logic
}
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior in Standard C.

Comment: Yes you are right. Its OP's choice to decide whether to terminate the program or continue to run. I have incorporated this in my answer.

Comment: @DavidBowling: Yes fflush is known to be inconsistent in the older glibc versions. But I think it should work on the newer versions. However, there is a warning that the code may have portability issues.

Comment: Thanks @DavidBowling. The discussion helped me understand many other things apart from a helpful answer. I appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks @iqstatic for the answer.

Comment: Well, `fflush(stdin)` has defined behavior in Windows, and as a GNU C extension, I believe, but is explicitly [undefined behavior in the Standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.2). It is certainly not portable, and I would suggest never using it as an illustration of a code solution.

Comment: What about `scanf` returning `EOF` (not 0)? I will use `if(scanf("%d", &choice) != 1){`

Comment: @KeineLust Right.

Comment: @DavidBowling Thanks for the reference. Certainly a learning for me.